# WPF - Open File Dialog WPF and Server

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-server-2008, openfiledialog

I'm having a problem using the OpenFileDialog (from System.Windows.Forms) in a WPF application running in a Windows Server 2008. When I click the button the mouse change to the "waiting mode", then turn normal and nothing happens, no one window is show. But, when I use the same method in a WindowsForm application, in the same server, it works.

I'm testing with this code:

```
try
{
    System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
    dialog.ShowHelp = false;
    dialog.Multiselect = false;

    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        return;

    txtCaminho.Text = dialog.FileName;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Exception: " + ex.Message);
}
```

The server is a Windows Server 2008, R2, x64, with .Net 4.5.2. The applications run in x86 mode.

I also tried to use the FileDialog from **Microsoft.Win32** and **Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs**

Comment: Works fine for me, must be something else in your project., Do you see this behaviour in a standalone test app?

Comment: Yes, this occurs in all WPF apps that use a OpenFileDialog, only in this server. The code I posted is from the standalone test itself.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is for 4.5 .Net and higher, there is one issue, that I met. Try rebuild your project for .net 4.0 and get back prior version. Then check .csproj file:
there you'll see extra tags in *`<PropertyGroup .../>`*:

```
<Prefer32Bit>false|true</Prefer32Bit>
```